# どうしてもね potential meaning

Tags: translation, manga, ellipsis, polarity-items

A and B are talking about a technology.

> A: Bは"technology"の導入には反対だったな
>
> A/B: reason 1 しreason 2 から,  どうしても……ね

I'm not sure what is the supposed meaning of どうしてもね here. Also the reason I'm using A/B is that I'm not 100% on who is supposed to be saying this (because manga). I at first thought that this is B replying to state their concerns. But now, I think it's A. Stating what they presume to be B's concerns.

I think どうしてもね might be a sort of saying "Is there any other reason?/anything else" and like. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me as it's B responding.

The どうしてもね means "I had to" or "I couldn't help but to" [due to the preceding reasons.] Basically they are saying their opposition to the technology was forced due to what they saw as overwhelming reasons.

Answer (score 5):

First, it would be more natural to assume that it is B who says the second line.  Call it a native speaker's gut feeling; I just could **not** imagine A saying it.  It sounds to me like a reply to A's line.

「どうしても・・・ね」 here would mean:

「どうしても賛成{さんせい}できないんだよね」 ("I can't [agree to it/approve of it] for the life of me.")

You will encounter 「どうしても」 again and again because we use it so frequently.

Comment: You have taken into account that those ellipsis is a pause before saying ne, right?
What does the ね add here and would you even bother translating it?
So this is: "because reason 1 and 2, I can't really approve...you know?"